# How to set FenceWidth in logarithmic plot?

Tags: plotting, bugs, logarithmic-scale

**Bug introduced in version 12.0 and persists in version 13.0**

---

Mathematica 12 introduced a built-in support for logarithmic plots with error bars. A plot with default styling looks as expected:

```
ListLogPlot[
    Table[{i, Around[1 + Sin[i], 0.1 + 0.1 Cos[i]]}, {i, 0, 10, 1}],
    PlotRange -> {All, {0.01, 10}}
    ]
```

[image]

However, when I want to customize `FenceWidth`, this happens:

```
ListLogPlot[
    Table[{i, Around[1 + Sin[i], 0.1 + 0.1 Cos[i]]}, {i, 0, 10, 1.0}],
    PlotRange -> {All, {0.01, 10}},
    IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceWidth" -> 0.3|>
    ]
```

[image]

What is a proper way to set custom `FenceWidth` in logarithmic plot?

How to set `FenceWidth` in absolute units like in default styling, when the width of fences doesn't change when the plot is resized?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is clearly a bug. In addition to the weird fence shape, the scaling behavior is also changed: fence widths change when the plot is resized.

A work-around is to post-process the output to straighten the fence lines and make fence widths independent of image size:

```
ClearAll[repairFences]
repairFences[w_] := Replace[#,  Line[x_] /; Length[Dimensions@x] ==  3 :>
  (Line[{Offset[{-w 72 /2 , 0}, #[[1,1]]], Offset[{w 72/2 , 0}, #[[1,1]]]}]& /@ 
    Partition[x, 2]), All] &

llp = ListLogPlot[Table[{i, Around[1 + Sin[i], 0.1 + 0.1 Cos[i]]}, {i, 0, 10,  1.0}],
       PlotRange -> {All, {0.01, 10}},
       IntervalMarkers -> "Fences",
       IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceWidth" -> .3|>
       ] ;

Row[Show[repairFences[.3] @ llp, ImageSize -> #]& /@ {200, 500}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

An alternative work-around is to remove `IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceWidth" -> .3|>` and post-process to modify the fence lines to desired length:

```
llp2 = ListLogPlot[Table[{i, Around[1 + Sin[i], 0.1 + 0.1 Cos[i]]}, {i, 0, 10, 1.0}],
     PlotRange -> {All, {0.01, 10}}, IntervalMarkers -> "Fences" ]
```

Make fences 20 printer's points long (fence length is independent of image size):

```
llp2 /. Offset[{a_, _}, b_] :> Offset[{10 Sign[a] , 0}, b]
```

[image]

Make fences .3 user units long (fence length changes with image size):

```
llp2 /. Offset[{a_, _}, {b_, c_}] :> {b + .15 Sign[a], c}
```

[image]

You can still use `IntervalMarkersStyle` to style the fences:

```
llp3 = ListLogPlot[Table[{i, Around[1 + Sin[i], 0.1 + 0.1 Cos[i]]}, {i, 0, 10, 1.0}],
     PlotRange -> {All, {0.01, 10}}, 
     IntervalMarkers -> "Fences",
     IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceStyle" -> Red|>];

 llp3 /. Offset[{a_, _}, {b_, c_}] :> {b + .5 Sign[a], c}
```

[image]

**Update:** using the second approach to make a function:

```
ClearAll[modifyFenceWidth]
modifyFenceWidth[arg : h_[w_] | w_] := # /.  Switch[Head[arg], 
     Offset, Offset[{a_, _}, b_] :> Offset[{ w  Sign[a]/2 , 0}, b], 
     Real, Offset[{a_, _}, {b_, c_}] :> {b + w/2 Sign[a], c},
     Scaled, Offset[{a_, _}, {b_, c_}] :> 
       {b + w Abs[Subtract @@ PlotRange[#][[1]]]/2 Sign[a], c}] &
```

***Examples:***

you can specify the fence width in user units, printer's points or as fraction of the plot width:

```
Row[Labeled[modifyFenceWidth[#] @ llp2, 
     Style["modifyFenceWidth @ " <> ToString[#], 18], Top] & /@ 
   {.4, Offset @ 20, Scaled @ .1}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]