# Plot mean of data with error bar

Tags: plotting, dataset

Suppose I have the following data with co-ordinates: {{1,190},{1,200},{1,210},{1,180},{1.5,175},{1.5,200},{1.5,190},{2,100},{2,150}}

How do I make a listplot of this data set, by taking the mean of the y-values for a particular x-value and then plotting an error bar. Since this is a small data set, I can evaluate mean and error easily, but what of there is a large data set, is there some way to automate the process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
data = {{1, 190}, {1, 200}, {1, 210}, {1, 180}, {1.5, 175}, {1.5, 
    200}, {1.5, 190}, {2, 100}, {2, 150}} ;

data2 = KeyValueMap[List]@ GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Around] (*thanks: Lukas Lang*)

ListPlot[data2]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[data2, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]],
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.15], 
 IntervalMarkersStyle -> <|"FenceWidth" -> .1, 
   "FenceStyle" -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
      "WhiskerStyle" -> Directive[Green, CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[20]]|>]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[data2, Joined -> True, 
 IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", IntervalMarkersStyle -> Green, PlotRange -> {0, 220}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, can you tell e what attribute should I change to change the color, boldness etc. of the error bar?

Comment: @Indeterminate, please see the update.

Comment: You should be able to just use `Around[#]`, and `Around` will automatically compute the mean and standard deviation (see the fourth usage case in [the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html))

Comment: Thank you @LukasLang; excellent point. Updated with your suggestion.

Comment: @kglr the solution with the 'whiskers' does not work on logarithmic axes. can it be adapted?

Comment: @Luigi, try the work-around in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/202767/125)?